# Can I change database schema dynamically on google app engine?

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing a REST google app engine application.

I want to know if it's possible to create a database schema dynamically.

What I mean is:

For example some client sends me and xml file with desired database schema(on a POST function).
After reading the xml file I want to create a database schema on google app engine datastore based on that xml.

Is it possible to create a desired schema even though I'm not creating a new java class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Java Low-Level Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary) to work with the datastore, it does't require a predefined schema.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I took a look and you are right, it will help me a lot. Regards